# error in Knitr using the rticles package: ! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \checkmark

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have a chunk, that when I knit it using standard knitr to pdd comes out as I expect it to:

````
---
title: "Test table"
author: "Derek Corcoran"
date: "February 20, 2017"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning =  FALSE)
```
````

### Tables

This is a $\psi$

````
```{r, results='asis', echo = FALSE}
library(xtable)
Softwares <- structure(list(X = structure(c(9L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("Alpha diversity models", "Build in model selection", 
"Built in response plot", "Multiple Species Abundance", "Multiple Species Single Season occupancy", 
"Priority area selection", "Single Species Abundance", "Single Species Dynamic occupancy", 
"Single Species Single Season occupancy"), class = "factor"), 
Diversityoccupancy = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "$\\checkmark$", class = "factor"), Unmarked = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("$\\checkmark$", 
"$\\checkmark$"), class = "factor"), stocc = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "$\\checkmark$", class = "factor"), 
Presence = structure(c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA
), .Label = "$\\checkmark$", class = "factor"), Pom = structure(c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "$\\checkmark$", class = "factor"), 
camptrapR = structure(c(1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), .Label = "$\\checkmark$", class = "factor")), .Names = c("X", "Diversityoccupancy", 
"Unmarked", "stocc", "Presence", "Pom", "camptrapR"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

names <- colnames(Softwares[,-1])
colnames(Softwares) <- c("", names)
print(xtable(Softwares, align = rep("c", 8)), scalebox='0.75', type = "latex", sanitize.text.function = function (x) x, include.rownames = F, comment=FALSE)


```
````

When I knit this this pdf comes out
[image]

However if I use the *rticles* package and use a template for a JSS article and insert the same chunk within it this comes out:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \checkmark
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `\usepackage{amsfonts}` in your YAML header:

```
preamble: >
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
```

The `\usepackage{amsmath}` is loaded by default when opening the JSS template, but not the amsfont package.